# SPARQL Prefix with Filter

Tags: xml, sparql

I'm trying to use a SPARQL Query in data.admin.ch:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT distinct (?z as ?Variable) (?ptype as ?Bevoelkerungstyp) (?remuniuri as ?Meldegmeinde) ?age ?sex ?person
where  
{ 
?z <http://data.admin.ch/bfs/property/POPULATIONTYPE> ?ptype. 
?z <http://data.admin.ch/bfs/property/REPORTINGMUNICIPALITYID> ?remuniuri. 
?z <http://data.admin.ch/bfs/property/AGE> ?age.
?z <http://data.admin.ch/bfs/property/SEX> ?sex.
```

I need to limit the ages to 7-22, but it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
SELECT distinct (SUM(xsd:int(?number)) AS ?child_inhabitants) WHERE
```

and then the with filter:

```
FILTER ((xsd:int(?pnumber)) <= 22 && (xsd:int(?agenumber)) <= 7)
```

Comment: Is it your data? If so, why are ages modeled as URIs?

Comment: Yes it's my. Because I need to filter out the Generation Z (1995 - 2010).

Comment: Ehm, I understand the FILTER but not why the ages in the dataset are modeled as URIs instead of plain integer values. That's what I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your query seems to be missing a closing `}`
- Both of your age filters are *less than*.
- How are ?number, ?pnumber or ?agenumber bound to the top portion of your query?

An alternative to Stanislav's answer, which doesn't use any string manipulation

```
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT  *
WHERE
  { ?z    <http://data.admin.ch/bfs/property/POPULATIONTYPE>  ?ptype ;
          <http://data.admin.ch/bfs/property/REPORTINGMUNICIPALITYID>  ?remuniuri ;
          <http://data.admin.ch/bfs/property/AGE>  ?age ;
          <http://data.admin.ch/bfs/property/SEX>  ?sex .
    ?age  skos:notation         ?ageval
    FILTER ( ( xsd:int(?ageval) <= 22 ) && ( xsd:int(?ageval) >= 7 ) )
  }
LIMIT   99
```